# How to run scripts in background in Neovim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I wish I could mimic original VIM behaviour by running scripts in the background and not in the internal Neovim terminal emulator.

Basically the reason is that I cannot seem to get colors to work properly, plus, I like to Ctrl+Z (put the editor in the background) and check what was the output of the last command.

Anyway I can configure nvim to do the same as vim in this regard?

Here is the comparison:

EDIT: My tests are run by using `:! ./vendor/bin/phpunit {file}`

VIM

[image]

NVIM

[image]

### EDIT

By "Background" I mean, not async, in the background while Neovim is on the "top". I mean, to place the editor in the background (like when we do ctrl+z, and then run the tests "on top". Then I hit a key and Neovim comes back to the top.

In other words, I want to configure nvim in a way that when I run a test, it is the same as doing CTRL-Z; execute test.

Sorry, this may be super confusing :D

Comment: Those gif screencasts are really hard to follow. It looks like you're using `:!{cmd}` to run the tests, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: That is correct. Thank you for the feedback. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `:!{cmd}`, I'd encourage you to experiment with running the tests via the `:te[rminal] {cmd}` command:

```
:te ./vendor/bin/phpunit {file}
```

That way the output from `phpunit` will be captured in a terminal buffer. You can switch between the terminal buffer and the test file using `<C-^>` (or `:b#`). Or you can open the terminal buffer and the test file side by side in separate windows. When you're finished with the terminal buffer, you can delete it using `:bwipeout {num}`.

One cool feature of terminal buffers is that if you place your cursor on a filepath and press `gf`, Vim will open the specified file. Better still, you use `gF`, then Vim will open the file at the specified line/column number, if those are present.

For more info, look up [`:help terminal`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_terminal_emulator.html#terminal) in Neovim.

Comment: Hum thanks! that sounds like something I can try to incorporate in my work flow. <C-^> or :b# is not taking me back to the terminal though...

Comment: Are you saying there's no way to do this in Neovim? In my use-case, I do _not_ want to capture any output from phpunit. Instead, I have a log file I trace.

Answer (score 1):

In newest version(HEAD version in github repo) of vim with terminal feature enabled.

You can run current file in background with following command:

:terminal ++hidden ./%

for neovim

You may need to install some plugin like:

https://github.com/tracyone/neomake-multiprocess

or

https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim

If you are using tmux, you can

https://gist.github.com/tracyone/65cffd685fc9b9308e50c1a1783d1fb0

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  It did not work though. The Async did nothing on my neovim. :terminal ++hidden just passes the arguments to the terminal, and then it complains ++hidden is invalid command. I did not try neomake-multiprocess yet.

Comment: You must install the latest vim from the source code of vim.

Comment: Vim already works the way I like in this case. It is on Neovim that I want to mimic this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:silent !./vendor/bin/phpunit {file}` to run the script background.

Comment: This runs the test asynchronously in a quickfix buffer. By background I mean, putting the editor in background (same as Ctrl+Z) and then running the tests in the terminal, outside the editor.